# Uniqueness of cointegration coefficient

Tags: stationarity, cointegration

Let $A_t$ and $B_t$ be $I(1)$ processes and assume that they are co-integrated i.e. there exists $\beta$ such that $A_t - \beta B_t$ is $I(0)$. Woolridge's Introductory Econometrics text (5th edition, page 646) claims that if we fix $A_t$'s coefficient at 1, then  $\beta$ unique.

A naive proof would be to assume to the contrary that there $\exists \delta \ne \beta$ and $A_t - \delta B_t$ is $I(0)$, then take difference of the two $I(0)$ processes to get $(\beta - \delta)B_t$. If difference of $I(0)$ processes is also $I(0)$, then we reach a contradiction, because $(\beta - \delta)B_t$, which is a scaler multiple of $B_t$, cannot be $I(0)$.

The issue is that it is generally not true that difference of $I(0)$ processes is also $I(0)$, unless they are jointly stationary. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/337636/is-stationarity-preserved-under-a-linear-combination).

Is there something that I am missing?

Edit: Rephrased the question, and as pointed out by @Richard Hardy, stationarity is not necessarily the same as $I(0)$, and the post I linked to deals with stationarity.

Comment: Good question! I think I get the gist but not the details of the naive proof. How is $(\beta-\delta)B_t\neq 0$ useful? Did you perhaps mean $(\beta-\delta)B_t$ is $I(1)$ and thus not $I(0)$? Also, you may note in your third paragraph that the linked thread deals with stationary rather than $I(0)$ processes. The relationship between these two categories might be a little ambiguous, since the definitions of $I(0)$ vary.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for the comments! Yes I was trying to say that $(\beta-\delta)B_t$ is not identically 0 because $\beta \ne \delta$, but I should have just said that it is not $I(0)$. I see your point about the differences between stationarity and $I(0)$.

Comment: Could you edit your post accordingly? I think that could make it easier to follow.